# Is it possible to create a css class that has dynamic value?

Tags: css

Assume that I have some div elements like these:

```
<div class="mystyle-10">Padding 10px</div>

<div class="mystyle-20">Padding 20px</div>

<div class="mystyle-30">Padding 30px</div>
```

Is it possible to create a class or something like :

```
.mystyle-*{padding: *px; margin-left: *px; border: *px solid red; }
```

that will replace the * with the value we set for the div's class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do u want to achieve it using css alone?

Comment: @amit : yep, only using CSS, not JQUERY or something else.

Comment: You could probably do it with [less](http://lesscss.org). But why not just write it out?

Comment: @bjb568 : Even less is a javavscript library rite. OP wants only using css which i don think is possible

Comment: @amit Well… it's kinda different if you do it server-side with Node.js.

Comment: @bjb568 : I don't want to write 100 classes just for 100 different padding values!

Comment: @quangtruong Bleh. If you want to use inline styles, use `style="padding: 123px"`. If you want to be nice and separate style from content, use just a few values (100 values is a lot anyway…). Or give your div a real class (something descriptive) so you can change your CSS in your _CSS_, not HTML. Basically, you asking this question shows that you don't know proper CSS use… and X-Y question.

Comment: Personally, I don't think there is a way to approach that with the use of css only. While there are many other tools such as less and scss can help with dynamic css generating, they also use some other technologies to implement their solutions

Comment: @bjb568 : It's just an example. I've updated the question, you will see that dynamic-value class is useful in this case.

Comment: @Quangtruong Still, you shouldn't use 100 unique classes just for padding. You can use 100 unique classes for different things (some floated, absolute, fixed, high-margin, low-margin, lost of colors, etc.), but not just for padding. If it's for 100 different things (you shouldn't really have this many, unless you have a complicated site, where you have the problem of having a complicated site), you will need to type it out anyway.

Comment: @quangtruong1985 I still think that pure JS must be used to achieve this. It would be about 10 lines of code. Won't hurt your website load time much. Or else, you would need less or scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @bjb568 said, you can easily achieve that using css pre-processors ( Sass, Less, Stylus .. etc )

below a [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) example

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
    .mystyle-#{ $i * 10 } {
        $result: ( $i * 10 ) + 0px;
        padding: $result;
        margin-left: $result;
        border: $result solid red;
    }
}
```

which will output the following:

```
.mystyle-10 {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 10px solid red;
}

.mystyle-20 {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 20px solid red;
}

.mystyle-30 {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border: 30px solid red;
}

.mystyle-40 {
    padding: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border: 40px solid red;
}

.mystyle-50 {
    padding: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border: 50px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target those elements with this selector - `[class^="mystyle-"]`, but the rest is not possible with plain CSS.